# repurpose a calculator with segmented lcd (raspberry pi / arduino)

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

I have this retro calculator, and a few spare raspberry pi and arduino / arduino nanos.
I've had the idea of turning this calculator into a text/doc reader using either a pi or arduino and its segmented display to scroll through the text. but i don't know where to start.
Any suggestions? Ideas? Tutorials? Examples, or similar projects?

[image]

thanks!

Comment: Wildly off-topic.  No code as required by `arduino` tag.  Nothing but a picture of an unknown device and request for some "suggestions" and "tutorials" (also off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Dismantle the calculator to see what kind of pins does the LCD have. After the you can just google "Arduino LCD" and get a lot of usefull projects like [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld). 
 
 Also Arduino is better than Pi for simple projects like this. Use Pi only when you need it, because Arduino is much easier to use.

Comment: Your link mentions "LCD displays that are compatible with the Hitachi HD44780 driver" . This won't apply to your calculator. Bad luck!

Comment: so i need to open up the calculator and get some specs on its segmented display, as a next step. I'll update this topic with specs and pics of the display asap. Thanks